# Is there any way to customize Google Play services Leaderboard on Android(Kotlin)?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, leaderboard

`I'm wondering if there is a way to customize the Default leaderboard UI of Google Play.`

Can we for example get a list of users and all attributes (Score, ID, name, icon, etc...) and make our own UI with Google Play game service leaderboard?

## Thank you!